# Parquet: read particular columns into memory

Tags: mapreduce, avro, parquet

I have exported a mysql table to a parquet file (avro based). Now i want to read particular columns from that file. How can i read particular columns completely? I am looking for java code examples.

Is there an api where i can pass the columns i need and get back a 2D array of table?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use hive, creating a hive table and issuing a simple select query would be by far the easiest option.

`create external table tbl1(<columns>) location '<file_path>' stored as parquet;
select col1,col2 from tbl1;
//this works in hive 0.14`

You can use JDBC driver to do that from java program as well.

Otherwise, if you want to stay completely in java, you need to modify the avro schema by excluding all the fields but the ones you want to fetch. Then when you read the file supply the modified schema as reader schema and it will only read the included columns. But you will get you original avro record back with excluded fields nullified, not a 2D array.

To modify the schema look at org.apache.avro.Schema and org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder. make sure that modified schema is compatible with the original schema.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Use Hive table to create table with all columns with storage format parquet and read the required columns by specifying the column names
2. Create Thrift for the table and use the thrift fields to read the data from code (Java or Scala)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apache drill that natively parse parquet files.